# Utilizing time in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift2, xcode7

I want to use 'time' in my app. I have a value "revenue per second", and then I want a label to tell me how much revenue I have made in total. 
So it should be like: revenue/s * amount of seconds elapsed = total revenue. I want the number to be changing all the time.
How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

```
var timer = NSTimer()
var counter = 0
var Revenue = 10
var revenueLabel = UILabel()
var secLabel = UILabel()

func count(){
    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval (
        1,
        target: self,
        selector: #selector(myProject.timerFunc),
        userInfo: nil,
        repeats: true
    )
}

func timerFunc(){
    revenueLabel.text = String(counter * Revenue) //Shows the totalRevenue generated per second
    secLabel.text = String(counter) // Shows the time elapsed
    counter += 1
}
```

Here you go. Hope this is helpful:)

Answer (score 0):

You need to look up the NSTimer class, it has a static method to create à timer that repeats itself infinitely.

You set it up to repeats every second and update a label with the new value, and you're good to go :)

Can't link now from my phone, but anyone feel free to edit my answer with the link to the doc